# Creating a default function parameter with templates

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, template-meta-programming

I am trying to make a method where the user can provide an analytic gradient function if available, but if not it defaults to using a  numeric gradient.

To that effect I tried the following:

```
template<typename V, typename S, S (*Fun)(const V&)> V NumericGradient(const V& p)
{
    const S e = 1.0e-6;
    return {
        Fun(p + V(e, 0, 0)) - Fun(p - V(e, 0, 0)) / S(2) * e,
        Fun(p + V(0, e, 0)) - Fun(p - V(0, e, 0)) / S(2) * e,
        Fun(p + V(0, 0, e)) - Fun(p - V(0, 0, e)) / S(2) * e,
    };
}

template<typename V, typename S = decltype(V()[0])>
std::vector<V> DualContouring(
    S (*DistanceFunction)(const V&),
    V (*GradientFunction)(const V&) = NumericGradient<V, S, decltype(DistanceFunction)>,
    const S span = S(50),
    const unsigned int resolution = 100)
{
    return {};
}
```

The compiler however is failing with this message (after instantiating it):

```
terrain_generation.cpp
../Src/examples/TerrainGeneration/terrain_generation.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<_RealType> DualContouring(S (*)(const V&), V (*)(const V&), S, unsigned int) [with V = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>; S = float]’:
../Src/examples/TerrainGeneration/terrain_generation.cpp:362:63: error: no matches converting function ‘NumericGradient’ to type ‘class Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> (*)(const class Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>&)’
  362 |         [](const Eigen::Vector3f& v) { return v.dot(v) - 10; });
      |                                                               ^
In file included from ../Src/Engine/Renderer/Renderer.hpp:24,
                 from ../Src/examples/TerrainGeneration/terrain_generation.cpp:32:
../Src/Engine/Geometry/DualContouring.hpp:97:56: note: candidate is: ‘template<class V, class S, S (* Fun)(const V&)> V NumericGradient(const V&)’
   97 | template<typename V, typename S, S (*Fun)(const V&)> V NumericGradient(const V& p)
      |                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../Src/examples/TerrainGeneration/terrain_generation.cpp:362:63: note:   when instantiating default argument for call to ‘std::vector<_RealType> DualContouring(S (*)(const V&), V (*)(const V&), S, unsigned int) [with V = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>; S = float]’
  362 |         [](const Eigen::Vector3f& v) { return v.dot(v) - 10; });
      |                                                               ^
../Src/examples/TerrainGeneration/terrain_generation.cpp: In function ‘void GenerateTerrain(Gallery&)’:
../Src/examples/TerrainGeneration/terrain_generation.cpp:362:63: error: no matches converting function ‘NumericGradient’ to type ‘class Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> (*)(const class Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>&)’
In file included from ../Src/Engine/Renderer/Renderer.hpp:24,
                 from ../Src/examples/TerrainGeneration/terrain_generation.cpp:32:
../Src/Engine/Geometry/DualContouring.hpp:97:56: note: candidate is: ‘template<class V, class S, S (* Fun)(const V&)> V NumericGradient(const V&)’
   97 | template<typename V, typename S, S (*Fun)(const V&)> V NumericGradient(const V& p)
      |                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [TerrainGeneration.make:156: obj/Debug/TerrainGeneration/terrain_generation.o] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:39: TerrainGeneration] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/makogan/vkengine/Generated'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "build.py", line 106, in main
    raise Exception("Compilation failed.")
Exception: Compilation failed.
```

I am not sure what's wrong with the type definitions there. The instantiation of `NumericGradient` should be type compatible with the expected function.

This is how I am trying to call the stub:

```
auto contour = DualContouring<Eigen::Vector3f, float>(
        [](const Eigen::Vector3f& v) { return v.dot(v) - 10; });
```

I am compiling with g++ 9.3 under linux.

#### Alternative problem

Ok I tried dropping the default arguments alltoghether and force the user to always pass the function pointer.

Somehow even this:

```
    float (*Distance)(const Eigen::Vector3f&) = [](const Eigen::Vector3f& v) {
        return v.dot(v) - 9;
    };
    auto contour = DualContouring<Eigen::Vector3f, float>(
        Distance, NumericGradient<Eigen::Vector3f, float>, Distance);
```

Fails to compile with error:

````
error: no matches converting function ‘NumericGradient’ to type ‘class Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> (*)(const class Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>&)’
  365 |         Distance, NumericGradient<Eigen::Vector3f, float>, Distance);```

Why? The template declaration should be fine.
````

Comment: ~Could you please give us an example of usage of DualContouring (w/ the definition of the types used in the example)?~
Duh, V = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>; S = float...

Comment: It would also be helpful if you mentioned the compiler you're using (w/ version).

Comment: @PedroBoechat I added the requested info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [Jarod42 explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499353/1833963), `NumericGradient`'s third template argument is a non-type argument and `decltype(DistanceFunction)` is a type. So, I believe what you wanted to do was to use `DistanceFunction`, but, as he mentioned, the argument name cannot be used in this context.

As an alternative, you could "demote" the function pointer template argument to a regular function pointer argument:

```
template<typename V, typename S> V NumericGradient(const V& p, S (*Fun)(const V&));
```

and pass it around.

Here's a working example:
https://godbolt.org/z/qhY938

As another alternative, you could pass `DistanceFunction` as a template argument to `DualContouring`.

Here's another working example:
https://godbolt.org/z/EnaMjK

Comment: The problem of demoting the function to a regular pointer is that it now forces the signature of the function to take 2 parameters instead of one, which messes up the interface I am trying to design.

Comment: Maybe you can pass DistanceFunction as a template argument to DualContouring, then? But then you cannot use a lambda anymore. I'll update my answer with that alternative.

Comment: I tried that too, it involves calling the first function inside the second, which apparently is not allowed. i.e. you cannot call the template argument inside the lambda on the signature.

Comment: Doesn't something like that suffice your needs: https://godbolt.org/z/EnaMjK?

Comment: It occurred to me that maybe you might want to use std::bind() to bind DistanceFunction to the GradientFunction and then pass the returned callable object to DualContouring as the GradientFunction. That way you don't need to pass the distance function to the GradientFunction from inside DualCountouring.

Answer (score 1):

`NumericGradient<V, S, decltype(DistanceFunction)>` is wrong, as third parameter should be a function pointer (a value), whereas you pass a type.

It would be `NumericGradient<V, S, DistanceFunction>`, but.. `DistanceFunction` is not a constant expression.

Comment: Why is it not a constant expression? Is it not determined at compile time?

Comment: Function parameters are not constant expression.